# Configuring `less` to show longer lines

Tags: less

I like to use less with `-S` flag to not break long lines.

But I also would like some indicator that one line is not fitting on the entire screen, so that i do not miss on information in case the lines looks like to end there.

Is there any option I am missing from reading the man pages that can show a special char on the last column in case a line is not fitting?

Comment: You may want to use `most` instead which does that by default.

Comment: how common is `most`? this is the first time i am hearing about it.

Comment: It's been around for decades. In my experience, on Linux distributions, it's usually available as a package though generally not installed by default.

Comment: I remember giving it a try many years ago. IIRC, while the display handling was far better than with `less`, my main concern was that it didn't support regexps for searching so I ended up reverting to `less`.